# Shutdown.exe is not shutting down system immediately, why?

Tags: c#, window, system-shutdown

I am using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-r -f -t 1")` to reboot server. This was running perfectly untill recently when I noticed the `server(win xp)` is not immediately shutting down. My logs showed application was running atleast 60 seconds after the `shutdown.exe` command.

so I started to wonder is there any reason/condition/etc that `shutdown.exe` was not able to shut the system down, even if -f was used.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling out to an executable, you can [call the API directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool InitiateSystemShutdownEx(
    string lpMachineName,
    string lpMessage,
    uint dwTimeout,
    bool bForceAppsClosed,
    bool bRebootAfterShutdown,
    uint dwReason);
```

If there is some issue, the exception should point you in the right direction.  For one, you must have the `SeShutdownPrivilege` and it must be enabled.

The complete code should look like the below when privileges are taken into account.  Note: this assumes use of the `System.Security.AccessControl.Privelege` class, which [was released in an MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163823.aspx), available for download [as linked from the article](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/e/9/2e9bde04-3af1-4814-9f1e-733f732369a3/TokenPrivileges.exe).

```
Privilege.RunWithPrivilege(Privilege.Shutdown, true, (_) =>
{
    if (!NativeMethods.InitiateSystemShutdownEx(null /* this computer */,
        "My application really needs to restart",
        30 /* seconds */, true /* force shutdown */,
        true /* restart */, 0x4001 /* application: unplanned maintenance */))
    {
        throw new Win32Exception();
    }
}, null);
```

This will perform the same function as what you are attempting to do by calling `shutdown.exe`, but most critically, will throw an exception if there is any failure or security restriction which prevents the shutdown from succeeding.

Comment: unfortunately my application is window service,I believe this API is for desktop apps only.

Comment: This is part of `advapi32`, which is definitely usable from a service.  `shutdown.exe` is just a wrapper on `InitiateSystemShutdownEx`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use slashes instead of dashes. `/r /f /t 1`